# RecyclerView load 10000+ image from backend api

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-paging

I get JSON data in my back-end API.

```
[
  {
    id: "is random"
    image: "my url"
  },
  ......10000+
]
```

My id is random number without continuity.

Each json object has image.

I call api and put data in `RecyclerView` .

But when `RecyclerView` is displayed, it will get stuck or crash.

I use Glide load image.

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(myUrl).placeholder(myPlaceholder).into(uiImage)
```

How can I let `RecyclerView` read it smoothly?

Can I use Paging Library to let it display five data at the beginning?

But I don't know which kind of `DataSource` is suitable for my json format.

`ItemKeyedDataSource`? or `PageKeyedDataSource`? or `PositionalDataSource`?

Update:

```
class MyAdapter(): ListAdapter<Item, ItemHolder>(Item.DIFF_CALLBACK){
   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, type: Int): ItemHolder=
        ItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent).also {}

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int): Unit = 
     with(holder) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        uiTextView.text = item.id
        GlideApp.with(context).load(item.image).placeholder(myPlaceholder).into(uiImage)
    }
}
```

Update:

```
class ItemHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup)
    : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_Item, parent, false)) {
    val uiTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_textView)
    val uiImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_image)
}
```

Sometimes it crashes if I remove the placeholder.

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(myUrl).into(uiImage)
```

Log message:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 3660 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: can you please post your adapter code? because ideally whatever the number of items, list should not crash as ViewHolder is efficient enough to handle that.

Comment: The type of datasource depends on how the API supports pagination.

Comment: Why worry? RecyclerView makes sure only visible items are loaded. Your Glide load should be in onBind, which is only called when it is becoming visible.

Comment: I post my adapter code.

Comment: By the way, when Glide didn't add a placeholder, it would often crash.

Comment: Try it by removing the whole image thing. Check whether it is still crashing while loading data?

Comment: what is your ItemHolder class? can you please post the code for that too?

Comment: Update my question.

Comment: Can you please add the log message which contains the exception for the crash?

Comment: show the crash log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**inject** *GlideApp*, instead of creating new instance every-time, which will make your app more smooth.

And also if you are using ***Paging Library***, then use **PagedListAdapter**.

Comment: ListAdapter extends Recyclerview.Adapter with DIFF feature. So it works same as Recyclerview.Adapter with some added functionality. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter

Comment: Thank you so much for updating my knowledge about new ListAdapter. :) @rafa